# How to write rspec for a model method in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Hi i have the following method in a my EnrolledAccount models for which i want to write rpec. My question is how can i create the association between Item and EnrolledAccount in rspec.

```
  def delete_account
    items = self.items
    item_array = items.blank? ? [] : items.collect {|i| i.id } 
    ItemShippingDetail.destroy_all(["item_id in (?)", item_array]) unless item_array.blank?
    ItemPaymentDetail.destroy_all(["item_id in (?)", item_array]) unless item_array.blank?
    Item.delete_all(["enrolled_account_id = ?", self.id])
    self.delete
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would use [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) to create a set of related objects in the database, against which you can test.

But, from your code I get the impression that your relations are not set up correctly. If you set up your relations, you can instruct rails what to do when deleting an item automatically.

E.g.

```
class EnrolledAccount
  has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :item_shipping_details, :through => :items
  has_many :item_payment_details, :through => :items
end

class Item
  has_many :item_shipping_details, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :item_payment_details, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

If your models are defined like that, the deletion will be automatically taken care of.

So instead of your `delete_account` you can just write something like:

```
account = EnrolledAccount.find(params[:id])
account.destroy
```

[EDIT] Using a gem like [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) or remarkable, writing the spec is then also very easy:

```
describe EnrolledAccount do
  it { should have_many :items }
  it { should have_many :item_shipping_details }
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank's for the help. Also i want to write rpec for this model. Can u help?

Comment: Added example with shoulda (or remarkable) to spec the relations.

Comment: I want to know if i can write rspec for the delete_account method.

Comment: If your relations are set up correctly, the `delete_account` method is no longer needed, and can be replaced by the standard ActiveRecord `destroy`. Since then you are calling standard ActiveRecord, there is imho no need to test it.